Get select list key within computed twig
I have a custom select list in a webform
In another field , I have some computed twig ,
I would need to get the selected value's key to apply some processing on the value
How do I get the select list's key  ?
the select list's yaml
you_are:
    '#type': select
    '#title': 'Are you an invidual or a company ? '
    '#title_display': invisible
    '#options':
      individual: 'Mr Individual'
      company: 'Company and co'

Somewhere in a computed twig field , I can only access the value of the select list
is there someway to do this with computed twig field ?
{% if data.you_are.KEY == "individual" %}
Do Something
{% endif %}

